# Some strange urls in joomla site

Tags: .htaccess, url, joomla, url-rewriting, duplicates

I have a site on joomla. I don't know how can I fix a problem with duplicate part in url. For example first url is

```
http://example.com/category/post
```

Second url:

```
http://example.com/category/post/category/post
```

This two urls shows the same. How can get rid of this? htaccess? or maybe joomla has a some tool?

Please help!

Comment: I think thats how Joomla works. I don't have much experience myself but if you try `http://example.com/category/post/category/post/category/post/category/post/category/post/category/post/category/post/category/post` It will work too ....

Comment: Yes you have right. It works but how can I prevent it? maybe some redirection ? from http://example.com/category/post/category/post to http://example.com/category/post  ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is a very old bug in Joomla, where any part before the `article` doesn't matter.

For example, the following links:

[joomlasite.com]/category-1/article-1.html

and:

[joomlasite.com]/blablabla/article-1.html

and:

[joomlasite.com]/blablabla/xyzxyz/article-1.html

will all work and will all display article-1.html. Granted, not all pages will look exactly the same (because the modules will be only assigned to "category-1"), but still, it is a big issue.

The best solution to this problem is to use canonical URLs. This will tell Google what the real link for any page is.

If the problem is small scale (only a few pages are affected), then you can address the issue with 301 redirects.